# How can i access a part of the Json string directly?

Tags: c#, json

I have a Json string as follows:

this is the variable json

```
   [
 {
     "Amount": 10.00,
     "Name": "UserTest",
     "Id": 12345,
     "UserItems": {
      "totalSize": 1,
     "records": [
      {
        "UserId": "1234589",
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Tester",
        "Street": "Test Street",
       }
      ]
     }
   }
 ]
```

Now to get to records i need to first parse this and access the records as follows:

```
 JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json);
```

I need to get the records and at the moment i am getting it by calling this :

```
 jsonObject["UserItems"]["records"]
```

and totalSize by

```
 jsonObject["UserItems"]["totalSize"]
```

The issue is that I dont know what the part "UserItems" will be. It can be any object , ContractItems, SalesItemsLines, etc etc

So is there any way i can get the totalSize directly and if it greater than 0 then get records directly ?

So for example if i try

```
   jsonObject["records"]
```

It gives null.

How can i get records directly ?

Comment: I don't know how to do it off the top of my head, but you have to iterate over child items until you get one with the name (string index) you're looking for. This is essentially a graph search problem.

Comment: `jsonObject.Children().OfType<JObject>().Where(o => (int)o["totalSize"] > 1)` maybe?

Comment: I will give that a go and let you know

Comment: I tried the following to get the value  jsonObject.Children().OfType<JObject>().Select(o => (int)o["totalSize"]).ToString();     But it just gave  System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject,System.Int32]

Comment: Why? Deserializing to an object is quick, and simple. You could literally call MyClass myInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyClass>>(jsonContent); then simply access the UserItems.Records like any list. https://json2csharp.com/ will even turn your json into a class (onceyou fix the missing comma after Id value.

Comment: The issue is I dont know what the class is , could be anything ? All i want is the value of the totalSize or the JArray of records ?

Answer (score 0):

since your json string is array, you have to use JArray.Parse() instead of JObject.Parse()

```
JObject userItems = (JObject) JArray.Parse(json)[0]["UserItems"];
 
JArray records = (JArray) userItems["records"];
```

after this you can get data

```
 int totalSize = (int) userItems["totalSize"];
 
 string firstName = (string) records[0]["FirstName"];
```